# XCode 11 Swift Menu Bar App - NSTextField freezes/disables

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm currently experimenting with MacOS Menu Bar Applications and I've stumbled across a problem. My Application looks like this (very basic): [Image of App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWbdw.png)

However, if the App goes in the background I can't write in the NSTextField anymore. It just turns grey like this: [Freezed NSTextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdy5O.png)

Here is my Code, I'm using a separate Swift Class with an .xib View Designer for the custom menu item view and instantiating it in a StatusBarController Class:

```
class StatusBarController {
  private var popover: NSPopover
  private var statusBar: NSStatusBar
  private var statusItem: NSStatusItem
  private var statusBarButton : NSStatusBarButton!

  var testView : Test!
   
  init(_ popover: NSPopover, _ menu: NSMenu?, _ firstMenuItem: NSMenuItem?, _ secMenuItem: NSMenuItem?) {
    self.popover = popover
    self.statusBar = NSStatusBar.init()
    self.statusItem = self.statusBar.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    
    
    self.statusBarButton = self.statusItem.button
    self.statusBarButton.title = "TEST"
    self.statusBarButton.action = #selector(self.togglePopover(sender:))
    self.statusBarButton.target = self
    
    if let menu = menu {
        self.statusItem.menu = menu
    }
    
    if let secMenuItem = secMenuItem {
        testView = Test(frame: NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 170.0))
        secMenuItem.view = testView
    }
  }

  @objc func togglePopover(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(popover.isShown) {
        self.hidePopover(sender)
    }
    else {
        self.showPopover(sender)
    }
  }

  ...
```

}

Does anyone know why or how to reenable the NSTextField?

Thanks!

Comment: Under what class are you writing code?

Comment: @ElTomato I've created a separate class for the custom view that is displayed in the images above together with a .xib file but with not much code in it, just loading the .xib file. And under the StatusBarController class shown above.

Comment: I don't know about others, but I have developed a dozen desktop applications with the status menu.  And I have never used a text field with them.

Comment: @ElTomato But is that the right way, if I want to get user input in the status bar application? Also I wanna say it's a status bar application only with no desktop application.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen a status menu that comes with a text field.  I suppose that the right way will be to prompt the user with an input box.  But have it in your own way.

Comment: @ElTomato How would you do that?

Comment: I don't know the purpose of a text field in your case.  If I need some input from the user, however, I would just show an input box, requesting the user to enter text.